# Unpack Binary Data with specific format in Julia

Tags: julia, binaryfiles, binary-data

I am trying to convert a Binary file parser to Julia from Python. I am struggling to figure out how to unpack the binary stream with a specific format. I found [this](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/packing-and-unpacking-binary-data/1638) discourse thread that is exactly what I am trying to do, but its from 2017 and doesn't seem to have a working solution. Does anyone have a solution?

In Python it looks like this:

```py
In [22]: struct.unpack('>idi', b'\x00\x00\x00\x17@\t\x1e\xb8Q\xeb\x85\x1f\x00\x00\x00*')
Out[22]: (23, 3.14, 42)
```

In Julia I am here:

```
data = open(filename, "r")
seek(data, 0)
# now I want to get the first 12 bytes of the file and convert to a string.. and am stumped..
```

Comment: I haven't tried it recently, but https://github.com/pao/StrPack.jl might be worth a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with `struct.unpack` in Python, but maybe you could do something like this:

```
julia> data = IOBuffer("\x00\x00\x00\x17@\t\x1e\xb8Q\xeb\x85\x1f\x00\x00\x00*")
IOBuffer(data=UInt8[...], readable=true, writable=false, seekable=true, append=false, size=16, maxsize=Inf, ptr=1, mark=-1)

julia> seekstart(data)
IOBuffer(data=UInt8[...], readable=true, writable=false, seekable=true, append=false, size=16, maxsize=Inf, ptr=1, mark=-1)

julia> i  = bswap(read(data, Int32))
23

julia> pi = bswap(read(data, Float64))
3.14

julia> i  = bswap(read(data, Int32))
42
```

`bswap`s are there because there seems to be a difference in endianness between what Julia internally uses and what's encoded in your binary stream. Apart from that, this is just a plain use of `read`, specifying the type of data to be read.

By the way, here is how you would read the first 12 bytes of the file, and convert them to a string (which is not really necessary in this case, but could be useful in others):

```
julia> seekstart(data)
IOBuffer(data=UInt8[...], readable=true, writable=false, seekable=true, append=false, size=16, maxsize=Inf, ptr=1, mark=-1)

julia> bytes = read(data, 12)
12-element Array{UInt8,1}:
 0x00
 0x00
 0x00
 0x17
 0x40
 0x09
 0x1e
 0xb8
 0x51
 0xeb
 0x85
 0x1f

# note the capital "S" in "String"
julia> String(bytes)
"\0\0\0\x17@\t\x1e\xb8Q\xeb\x85\x1f"
```

Comment: Thanks! yep I just figured it out.. this is my first attempt at a binary parser and it just took a little of time for it to seep into my thick head..